# I have a javascript timer but I want the timer to continue even if I refresh or restart the browser

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, timer

I am using a countdown timer I've found in google, I just modify some line of codes to make the timer to **count up** instead of counting down. I just want my timer to count up then it stops when I click the stop button. My problem is I want the timer to not reset even if the page is refresh or the browser is restart. From what I know I need to use cookies for this but I don't know how to incorporate it to my code. Please help..

Here's my code.

```js
(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var time = "00:00:00",
      parts = time.split(':'),
      hours = +parts[0],
      minutes = +parts[1],
      seconds = +parts[2],
      span = $('#countup');

    function correctNum(num) {
      return (num < 10) ? ("0" + num) : num;
    }

    var timer = setInterval(function() {
      seconds++;
      if (seconds > 59) {
        minutes++;
        seconds = 0;

        if (minutes > 59) {
          hours++;
          seconds = 0;
          minutes = 0;

          if (hours >= 24) {
            alert("timer finished");
          }
        }
      }
      span.text(correctNum(hours) + ":" + correctNum(minutes) + ":" + correctNum(seconds));
    }, 1000);
  });
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="countup">00:00:00</span>
```

Comment: That is not possible until you make some mechanism so store the lastest time frame in some local or server storage. On local side, you can user ``localStorage``

Comment: Hi @NotABot can you help me to incorporate it with my code? I'm not really sure on how to do it or you can just give me a hint on how to do it. Thank you.

Comment: See you can find that either user has reload/close window(browser) using **beforeunload** and then store the time frame in ``localStroage``  Please read about  beforeunload event here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event

Comment: Thanks for the link @NotABot will read about beforeunload to understand further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Working script using 24 seconds instead of 24 hours](http://plungjan.name/ee/persistent/counter.html) - it will reset after timer is finished so next time the page is refreshed it starts from 0

Uncomment the lines to have a working script.

NOTE change

```
var savedDate = "", // +localStorage.getItem("date"),
```

to

```
var savedDate = +localStorage.getItem("date"),
```

```js
const pad = (num) => ("0" + num).slice(-2);

$(function() {
  var savedDate = "", // +localStorage.getItem("date"),
    date = new Date();
  if (savedDate && !isNaN(savedDate)) date = new Date(savedDate);
  else date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);


  var hours = date.getHours(),
    minutes = date.getMinutes(),
    seconds = date.getSeconds(),
    $span = $('#countup');

  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    date.setSeconds(date.getSeconds() + 1);
    if (date.getHours() >= 24) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      $span.text("timer finished");
      // localStorage.removeItem("date");
    } else {
      $span.text(
        pad(date.getHours()) + ":" +
        pad(date.getMinutes()) + ":" +
        pad(date.getSeconds())
      );
      // localStorage.setItem("date", date.getTime())
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="countup"></span>
```

Comment: This also worked too.. but I want my timer to start counting from 00:00:00. Anyway, thanks for sharing your knowledge this will be a great help for me and to others in the future. God bless.

Comment: when i tried the code above it will reset every time I refresh the page.

Comment: It will still reset when I refresh the page.

Comment: Actually, i want my timer to not reset whenever I refresh or restart my browser. Your first answer is what I need the only problem is I want it to start counting up from 00:00:00 then stops when I click the button stop, your answer starts at a given time, I want it from 00:00:00 then stops whenever I click the stops button.

Comment: the code I have posted will start from 00:00:00 whenever started from scratch or reloaded after the test of 24 hours expires

Comment: [My latest version](http://plungjan.name/ee/persistent/counter.html) will start running when you click start and continue to run when reloaded until 24 hours have passed or you click stop. After this you can reload the page to see the start button again

Answer (score 0):

I think u should use localstorage for store time. its better to store time on unload page event

Comment: You should elaborate your answer a bit, adding documentation or code snippets and explaining how it would work for others

Comment: Thank you. Yes, you're correct. I am providing a blog link as a reference.
[JS Countdown Using Localstorage Blog](http://circle.codesolution.in/blog/js-countdown.php)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to persist a countdown is probably to save the end of the countdown as a fixed point in time (such as a UNIX timestamp, which JavaScript has support for) and then re-calculate the difference between local time and the saved time when the page loads. There are actually such handly libraries that help out with time operations, such as Moment.js.

I would recommend using LocalStorage over cookies, cookies are also sent to the server, and are designed more for authentication/session tokens. Here's a good article to get started:

https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-use-local-storage-with-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

You can use for example localstorage to save timer there and then just to use it.
Please try below example:

```
// Set an item to localstorage
localStorage.setItem('name', 'value');

// Read the item from localstorage
localStorage.getItem('name'); => // => 'value'
```

In your code it should look like:

```
(function(){
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var time = localStorage.getItem('timer') || "00:00:00",
        parts = time.split(':'),
        hours = +parts[0],
        minutes = +parts[1],
        seconds = +parts[2],
        span = $('#countup');

    function correctNum(num) {
        return (num<10)? ("0"+num):num;
    }

    var timer = setInterval(function(){
        seconds++;
        if(seconds > 59) {
            minutes++;
            seconds = 0;

            if(minutes > 59) {
                hours++;
                seconds = 0;
                minutes = 0;

                if(hours >= 24) {
                  alert("timer finished");
                }
            }
        }

        var displayTime = correctNum(hours) + ":" + correctNum(minutes) + ":" + correctNum(seconds);
        localStorage.setItem('timer', displayTime);
        span.text(displayTime);
    }, 1000); 
  }); 
})()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @Oleh Morozov it worked!!! This literally saves a lot of time. Been working for 2 days for this trying to figure it out. God bless!